# Excel filtering on text between 2 alphabetic values

Tags: excel

I have a list of different two letter combinations that are the 'aisle ranges' in a warehouse. E.g. AA/BA/BG these are all different aisle names in the warehouse racking.

What I would like to to is be able to filter on this column but I would like to filter values that are in between 2 different aisle ranges. I.e. Put a filter to show any aisle that is alpabetically between AA - BC. In my example this would bring back AA, AB, AC, BA, BB and BC.

Is there a way to do this through the filter function in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Add a filter for this column, then click on the filter button (down arrow), select text filter then "Personalize Filter...".

Then use:

"Bigger than or equal to" -> type AA

select AND

"Smaller than or equal to" -> type BC.

Sorry if the names aren't exactly those, My excel is not in english.

Answer (score 0):

The `Code` function, which can convert a letter to its ASCII value, may be helpful here.  Consider the following formula:

```
=26*(CODE(MID(A1,1,1)) - 65) + CODE(MID(A1,2,1)) - 64
```

This formula will convert a two letter aisle code into a numerical position, starting with 1.  You may copy this formula down to cover all your aisles.  Then, filter numerically using the same function.

By inspection, the above formula would render `AA` as `1`, `AB` as `2`, and `AZ` as 26.  `BA` becomes `27`, and so on, with the first letter wrapping with each complete cycle of the second letter.